# How to implement CSS file style on selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use CSS files on paricular div style. and all other site design style not effect with my CSS files.

inline styling or !important in not possible because i have thousands lines of code.

Comment: The fact you use a javascript tag in this message wonders me if you need / want to use javascript in your code in order to achieve your goal. Your question in common is very vague and it would require some brushing up, however you have your answers below here, so far CSS as for Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just give an id for that div and use that id in ur stylesheet.

for ex.

```
<div id="Test">
------
--------
</div>

<style>
#Test .yourclass {
----
-----
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve this via Javascript:

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('your Element').style.color="red"
```

jQuery:

```
$('#your Element').css('color','red');
```